# Matlab ResizeFcn callback

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am worried about the look and feel of my GUI designed with Matlab. In concrete, I do not like how the figure window resizing is achieved. I have an uitabgroup (tabpanel) inside which there are three panels with border etchedin. Each time the figure is resized, it appears flickering between both positions of the panels. I hate this optical effect. So, I decided to build my own resizefcn callback to get being pleased. However, I realize Matlab first resizes the figure window  and then it runs the commands inside the resizefcn callback. I would like to know if there is some solution that lets me to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758) may help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, GUI Layout Toolbox has not avoided the flickering.